# Cross-references in RMarkdown for Word documents

Tags: r, label, r-markdown

I am writing an Rmd file that will be knitted to a report in Word. 
I am trying to create a label for a figure, and a cross reference to it, as in:

> As illustrated in Figure `\ref{fig:TotalCarStock}`, etc, etc.

````
```{r TotalCarStock, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Forecasted versus actual car stock", out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("C:/Usr/WP vehicle stock/TotalCarStock.jpg")
```
````

All discussions I have seen here indicate that this works correctly when creating a pdf document, but I wish to "knit" my Rmd file to a Word document. The Word document is created correctly, except that the label and the cross reference remain blank.

Answer (score 5):

@LaurentFrankx Finally, I found the solution: you will be able to get the following result, if you use `bookdown::word_document2:` instead of `word_document` in the `output` line of YAML header, as shown below.

[image]

````
---
title: "VHS Report"
author: "Laurent Franckx"
date: "14 September 2018"
output: 
  bookdown::word_document2:
  fig_caption: yes
#pdf_document: default
---

As illustrated in Figure \@ref(fig:TotalCarStock), etc, etc. However, `out.width = '100%'` in an R chunk cannnot be specified when we want to produce a `.docx` output, because `out.width = '100%'` is used for creating `.pdf` outcome.

```{r TotalCarStock, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Forecasted versus actual car stock"}
knitr::include_graphics("https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlNbf.png")
```
````

`bookdown::word_document2:` and other `***_document2` functions are created by @Yihui. We can see their usage in the official [guidebook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/a-single-document.html). These enable us to put the automatic numbering, as described in [here](https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/content/3060/Word_Up_Gotta_Get_Up_To_Get_Bookdown.html#word_document2()_huh).

For farther customization, we can consult the article titled [*Happy collaboration with Rmd to docx*](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html). Although the article introduces how to configure the formatting with `word_document`, the tips are still valid and useful with the updated function, `word_document2`.

Comment: Brilliant! This did indeed solve the problem. Thank you so much. Just out of curiosity, where did you find this? (I just used the default header provided by RStudio)

Comment: @LaurentFranckx Sorry for my late reply, but I'm happy to hear your success! I edited the answer and added the source of `word_document2`.

Comment: Great answer, and it worked. However! - the name of the reference doesn't like underscores. I just spent ages trying to find out why it wasn't working. I was using `fig:Total_Car_Stock` and `{r Total_Car_Stock...`, (or the equivalent in my document) which doesn't work, but `fig:TotalCarStock ` and `{r TotalCarStock...` does work for some reason. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Answer (score 3):

According to [the Rmarkdown guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html) by the creator @Yihui, `\@ref(figure's label)` should be used to refer to a figure. Therefore, you may use `\@ref(fig:TotalCarStock)`, instead of `\ref{fig:TotalCarStock}`, as shown below:

> As illustrated in Figure \@ref(fig:TotalCarStock), etc, etc.

The notation `\@ref(figure's/table's label)` can be used to make a reference to an image, graph or table, when knitting either `.docx`, `.pdf`, or `.html`.

Comment: Actually, I had already tried to implement this. I then got the following output: "As illustrated in Figure @ref{fig:TotalCarStock}, the forecasted car stock is much higher than the actual car stock"

Comment: I oversaw a fundamental solution: your file path may need to be fixed. Currently, your file path is `C:/Usr/WP vehicle stock/TotalCarStock.jpg`, which includes some ` ` (spaces). That seems cause the problem. If possible, could you rename the path so that the file path has no space? (e.g. `C:/Usr/WP-vehicle-stock/TotalCarStock.jpg`) I think `-` (hyphen) is more convenient than `_` (underscore), because sometimes TeX engines fail to read a path with underscores. Although I know that you want a `.docx` output , using `-` is safer way as far as I know.

Comment: I have modified this, put the problem persists. It also arises when I create graphs that are created directly in the R chuncks with ggplot2. Actually, even my figure captions don't contain a number. So I thought that maybe the issues is in the beginning:---
title: "VHS Report"
author: "Laurent Franckx"
date: "14 September 2018"
output:
  word_document:
    fig_caption: yes
  #pdf_document: default
---

Comment: @LaurentFranckx As you have already noted, the key lies in your YAML header. I added another solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create cross references in R markdown documents using [quarto](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/).

Document example modified from the [quarto MS-Word documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/ms-word.html):

````
---
title: "Pressure Pressure"
format:
  docx:
    toc: true
---

# Section name

```{r echo=FALSE}
#| label: fig-plot
#| fig-cap: "Plot"
plot(pressure)
```

For example, see @fig-plot.
````

Render this document with

```
    quarto render document.qmd
```

[image]